# How can I set the height of an element equal to another element? (Codepen included)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two Bootstrap columns with 4 divs (2 in each):

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="cell-1">
      Cell 1
    </div>
    <div class="cell-2">
      Cell 2
      <ul>
        <li>Some repeatable text</li>
        <li>Some repeatable text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="cell-3">
      Cell 3
    </div>
    <div class="cell-4" style="overflow-y:auto; max-height:[height of cell-2]">
      Cell 4
      <ul>
        <li>Lots of repeatable text</li>
        <li>Lots of repeatable text</li>
        <li>Lots of repeatable text</li>
        <li>Lots of repeatable text</li>
        <li>Lots of repeatable text</li>
        <li>Lots of repeatable text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

`.cell-4` has `overflow-y: auto`. How can I set the `max-height` of `.cell-4` equal to the dynamic height of `.cell-2`?

Ideally without Javacript.

Codepen here: [link](https://codepen.io/alias51/pen/pogzBNK)

Comment: i know it says `ideally without javascript` but im just here incase you decide javascript can be used: `$('.cell-4').css('max-height', $('.cell-2').height());` this would be all you need (actually jquery code)

Comment: to achieve what you want, you need to change the structure of your HTML

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex` and `align-items: stretch`.

```
.col-4{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't see how to apply this. Could you show me on the codepen please? https://codepen.io/alias51/pen/pogzBNK

Comment: I've looked into this further, it doesn't appear to work as there's no max-height for the overflow. I assume you don't mean `align-items:center` either? Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the CSS flexbox configuration to make it work. col-4 and col-8 are configured to flex column. Then, cell-4 add the flex-basis and flex-grow configuration.

```css
.cell-1{
  background: red;
}
.cell-2{
  background: blue;
}
.cell-3{
  background: green;
}
.cell-4{
  background: pink;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  /* overflow-y: scroll; */
  /* max-height: 50px; // Set this to equal height of Cell 2 */
  /* Addition flex configuration to make it work */
  flex-basis: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

/* Addition flex configuration to make it work */
.col-4, .col-8 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-8">
    <div class="cell-1">
      Cell 1
    </div>
    <div class="cell-2">
      Cell 2
      <ul>
        <li>Some repeatable text</li>
        <li>Some repeatable text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <div class="cell-3">
      Cell 3
    </div>
    <div class="cell-4" style="overflow-y:auto; max-height:[height of cell-2]">
      Cell 4
      <ul>
        <li>Lots of repeatable text</li>
        <li>Lots of repeatable text</li>
        <li>Lots of repeatable text</li>
        <li>Lots of repeatable text</li>
        <li>Lots of repeatable text</li>
        <li>Lots of repeatable text</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```